# Node JS Requests get returns response code 401 for nse india website

Tags: node.js, stockquotes

I use this program to get the json data from https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY but since this morning it's not working as it returns <Response [401]>. The link loads fine on chrome though. Is there any way to fix this without using axios?

Comment: https://github.com/maanavshah/stock-market-india check this

Comment: Thank you @RameshKR for this reference. I am thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried same thing with node js
please use node js ide [link here for online ide](https://replit.com/@larer50497/NSEINDIAAPI)
please review my code

```
const axios = require('axios');


let cookie;
let url_oc = "https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain"
let url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
let headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)',
  'accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
}

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: url_oc,
  headers: headers,
  cookie: cookie ? cookie : ""
});



const getCookies = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await instance.get(url_oc);
    cookie = response.headers['set-cookie'].join();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 403) {
      console.log("getCookies =========> error.status === 403");
      await getCookies()
    } else {
      console.log("getCookies =========> error");
    }
  }
}


const getAPIData = async () => {
  try {
    if (cookie) {
      const response = await instance.get(url);
      console.log(response.data.records.timestamp);
    }

  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      console.log("getAPIData =========> error.status === 401");
      if (!cookie) {
        console.log("getAPIData =========> cookie not found");
        await getCookies()
      }
      await getAPIData()
    } else {
      console.log("getAPIData =========> error");
    }
  }
}



(async () => {
  setInterval(async () => {
    await getCookies()
  }, 5000);

  setInterval(async () => {
    await getAPIData()
  }, 3000);
})()
```